# Cómo Recorrer Un xml con php

Tags: php

Buenos días estoy tratando de correr un xml pero cuando uso la clase SimpleXMLElement se pierden algunas etiquetas quiero saber como puedo hacer par que no se pierdan las etiquetas la que necesito es la etiqueta title.

```html
$curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://anchor.fm/s/11035988/podcast/rss",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Accept: */*",
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
      "Connection: keep-alive",
      "Host: anchor.fm",
      "Postman-Token: aab38a2c-8c38-407a-8cc4-7b32455f1ad4,f862afdb-5462-4734-95f7-c1cd0251737a",
      "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.18.0",
      "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err      = curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  $xmPod        = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
  $arrayPodcast = $xmPod->channel->item;
```

Así es como como se ve cuando hago uso de la clase

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La clase [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) es más robusta, más completa y más fiable para trabajar con XML. De todos modos si no vemos lo que tienes en `$xmPod` no podremos decirte cómo hacer para leerlo. En tu código no muestras nada en la salida.

Comment: Si se analiza el resultado que obtienes actualmente, todos los `title` vienen vacíos, el único que tiene algo es el de `image` al cual puedes acceder así: `$image=$xmPod->channel->image; echo $image->title;` en cuyo caso la salida sería: `Los Estrategas`. No sé si es eso lo que buscas ¿?

Comment: Buenos días, muchas gracias por el apoyo si haces un print_r al $response muestra el árbol completo de hecho si ejecuta https://anchor.fm/s/11035988/podcast/rss url en el nacegador muestra el árbol la información que necesito está item->title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la petición está devolviendo contenido con `CDATA`, por eso en las pruebas simples no veía bien los datos.

El problema de `CDATA` se puede tratar usando [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-string.php) al cual le podemos pasar como tercer parámetro la constante: `LIBXML_NOCDATA`, que nos limpiará el contenido de `CDATA` y nos permitirá, ahora sí, acceder de forma natural a las etiquetas como `title`.

Asumiendo que en `$response` tienes el contenido devuelto por el flujo rss:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Veamos ahora el contenido:

```
var_dump($xml);
```

Ahora sí sale bien:

**Salida:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["version"]=>
    string(3) "2.0"
  }
  ["channel"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (10) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(14) "Los Estrategas"
    ["description"]=>
    string(517) "La misión de este podcast es clara: Formar Estrategas centrados en principios que combatan la pobreza y la corrupción, empezando por si mismos.

.....
```

Y, siguiendo la estructura, vemos que `title`  se encuentra dentro de la etiqueta `channel`, por tanto accedemos tal cual:

```
var_dump($xml->channel->title);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "Los Estrategas"
}
```

Y podemos hacer `echo` también:

```
echo $xml->channel->title;
```

**Salida:**

```
Los Estrategas
```

---

Si lo que interesa es el `title` del `item`, sólo hay que seguir la estructura del documento para encontrarlo, accederemos a `channel`, luego a `item` y luego a `title`:

```
var_dump($xml->channel->item->title);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(61) "Los Estrategas Ep#06 - ¿Por qué no logras tus metas? parte2"
}
```

Y así, para cualquier dato que te interese.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente explicación me funciono perfecto bendiciones